# How do I get my table images to be the same size?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I've created a table with images all sized 150x150px yet some images are showing larger/smaller than others.

Annoyingly, when I put the code into JSFiddle it seems to be fine. Yet in my site (using Wordpress) some of my images show larger/smaller ect.

[The JSFiddle can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/86n8a451/).

The table "in action!" can be seen at:

```
http://79.170.44.112/activate-enterprise.co.uk/meet-the-team/
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [Read this if your 'code is too long to put it here'](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the error, it's your wordpress style :

On the image you have this design :

```
media="all"
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

If you remove this design, your images are showed properly.

```
img {
    max-width : inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't find this in my stylesheet? Would you know where this would be?

Comment: i think it's in default wordpress style. overwrite this in your css file

Comment: Found and removed!! Worked a treat!

Comment: Will accept as best answer after the time limit has passed...!

Answer (score 0):

You have `max-width: 100%;` in one of your styles for the `img` tag.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I feel by setting the `max-width: inherit`, your problem will solve.